# express-session req.session.touch not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-session

I'm working on a personal project, recently included express-session and cookie-session. Though i'm having a problem when navigating to localhost:3000/, i get an error telling me that req.session.touch is not a function in express-session module. Below you can find a snippet of the code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');
const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session')
let cookieSession = require('cookie-session')
const pug = require('pug');
require('./db/mongoose');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Todo = mongoose.model('Todo');
const User = mongoose.model('User');
let app = express();
const ObjectID = require('valid-objectid');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Use session
app.use(session({ secret: 'secretomitted', cookie: { maxAge: 0 } }))

//Set cookie session
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cookieSession({ name: 'session', secret: 'secretomitted', maxAge: 0 }))

//Set views folder and view engine
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function (email, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ 'email': email }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, console.log('Wrong username'));
      }
      if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, console.log('Wrong Password'));
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


//FE Requests

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(pug.renderFile('index.pug'))
  console.log('index rendered')
})
```

and this is the error i'm getting:

```
[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server/server.js`
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option server/server.js:24:9
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option server/server.js:24:9
Started on port 3000
/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/express-session/index.js:326
        req.session.touch()
                    ^

TypeError: req.session.touch is not a function
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/express-session/index.js:326:21)
    at Array.write (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:297:9)
    at listener (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
    at callback (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (/Users/alessandrocamplese/Desktop/Projects/Mongo-tasker/mongo-tasker/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Any solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

#### TL;DR: Only use one session management, for custom session information extend the session object don't overwrite it.

Old question, but I had the same issue, so for anyone else trying to accomplish the same thing :) . I believe that the problem is some sort of conflict from different session objects:

```js
//Use session
app.use(session({ secret: 'secretomitted', cookie: { maxAge: 0 } }))

//Set cookie session
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cookieSession({ name: 'session', secret: 'secretomitted', maxAge: 0 }))
```

This is using express-session AND cookie-session. Here is a quote from [expressjs.com](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html):

> A user session can be stored in two main ways with cookies: on the server or on the client. [cookie-session] stores the session data on the client within a cookie, while a module like express-session stores only a session identifier on the client within a cookie and stores the session data on the server, typically in a database.

As explained above, express-session only stores an ID in the cookie, while cookie-session stores all session data in the cookie. This [very short blog post](https://davidburgos.blog/expressjs-session-error-req-session-touch-not-function/) explains how messing with the session data will cause your error. The two types of session storage will inevitably cause such a conflict, since they are trying to store the data in different places.